# How to add graphics lines in a grid?

Tags: graphics, user-interface

I am creating a GUI for an application which presents a grid of check boxes. The user can check a box to display a specific part of a graphics image. The following is a simple version of a more complex interface:

```
line1 = CheckboxBar[{1, 3}, {1 -> "1", 2 -> "2", 3 -> "3"}]
line2 = CheckboxBar[{1, 5}, {1 -> "{A,B}", 2 -> "{C}"}]
mygrid = {};
mygrid = Append[mygrid, {line1}];
mygrid = Append[mygrid, {line2}];
Grid[mygrid]
```

This would present check boxes with labels like:

[image: grid]

The graphics includes links between the rows of check boxes and I would like to identify these links with arrows.  For example, I could have a link from `3` on the first row to the `{C}` on the second row.  Would be very informative if I could include an arrow in the grid from from any check box in row $i$ to any check box in row $i+1$.  For example could I draw an arrow from `3` to `{C}`?

Or could you guys suggest another interface I could effect this design?

Comment: What you specifically ask for: drawing arrows between cells in `Grid` construct is beyond my abilities, but I can't categorically say it is impossible. However, I do not recommend trying to go down that path. There are two possibilities that I think are much more feasible: 1) use graphs and `GraphPlot`, 2) use `Inset` (to hold the check boxes) and `Graphics`.

Comment: @Dominic, One seldom needs to Append a vector or array in Mathematica. Your code would give the same result if skipped 'mygrid' and used      Grid[{{line1}, {line2}}].

Answer (score 2):

Ok thanks.  I think I can use something like:

```
g1 = Graphics[{Inset[Checkbox[True], {0, 5}], Text["{1,2}", {0.5, 5}],
 Inset[Checkbox[True], {2, 5}], Text["{3}", {2.5, 5}]}];
g2 = Graphics[{Inset[Checkbox[True], {0, 4}], Text["{3}", {0.5, 4}], 
Inset[Checkbox[True], {2, 4}], Text["{2}", {2.5, 4}]}];
a1 = Graphics[Arrow[{{0, 4.8}, {0, 4.2}}]];
Show[{g1, g2, a1}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 6}, {-1, 6}}]
```

That draws an arrow from checkbox {1,2} on the first row to checkbox {3} on the second.  And I assume I can use the same interface I'm using to retrieve all the (dynamic) check mark data.  And also this way I have better control of placement of all the data in the GUI.

Comment: I'd recommend to use `ImageSize->{120, 70}` instead of `PlotRange`.

Answer (score 0):

```
LayeredGraphPlot[
 {Button["1"] -> Button["A"], 
  Button["2"] -> Button["B"], 
  Button["3"] -> Button["C"]},
 DirectedEdges -> True,
 VertexRenderingFunction -> ({EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, Disk[#1, 0.15],
      Black, Text[#2, #1]} &)]
```